# Entering Vim mode in atom

Tags: vim, atom-editor

Once you install the vim packages using the command line in atom, how do you actually enter vim mode in atom as soon as you enter atom? What I mean is once you are on the plain text editor screen what are the steps needed to enter vim mode?

Ps I only installed one vim package I am sure that is enough.

Comment: if vim is your weapon, why pick atom, and installed vim-mode/package?

Comment: @Kent Atom's plugin manager is better. Vim is a powerful weapon, but the transition to vim can be daunting for some people. It's like learning to play an F major chord on guitar - most people end up quitting. Atom allows you to ease your way into vim. Atom is also prettier with a web-based UI. I'm not sure about this one, but perhaps atom has a larger community?

Comment: @Parm  Atom has a lot of things that vim doesn't have like web-UI, eye-candy..... But it cannot do all things vim is able to do either. If a user just wants to use h,j,k,l,d,c,s... in another editor. It's fine. But if one wants to feel the real productivity of vim, I don't think Atom is a satisfied tool for him. I don't want to compare the two tools. Just use your guitar example, because I play guitar as well. There are songs you can play with just C, E and G. If they are all that you need, fine. If you want to play more songs, you have to learn F and many much more difficult chords.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the latest version is [vim-mode-plus](https://atom.io/packages/vim-mode-plus) and the previous version vim-mode is deprecated.

You need to type `atom` before `vim` command.

For instance, if you type atom, it should be listed as a command:

[image]

Then you can type `vim` and the file-name like:

```
atom vim example.py
```

Then you will see the cursor on the upper left corner

[image]

Then you can start coding with the atom. The other choice is using Idea-vim in Pycharm. I agree with Kent because atom editor will enable to use of previous and vim key combinations. For testing your code you need command-prompt, so why atom?